# How to find the position(s) of a number in a 2D array?

Tags: rust

For example, how could I find the positions that contain the value 20 in the following 2D array?

```rust
let nested_array = [
    [17, 16, 15, 14, 13],
    [18, 5, 4, 3, 12],
    [19, 6, 1, 2, 11],
    [20, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [21, 20, 23, 24, 25],
];
```

Values might not be unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could either roll your own `for` loop. Alternatively, you can use [`find()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find) or more specifically [`find_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find_map) and [`position()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.position):

```rust
let find = 20;

let pos = nested_array.iter().enumerate().find_map(|(i, arr)| {
    let j = arr.iter().position(|x| x == &find)?;
    Some((i, j))
});
```

We can assert that we get the correct value:

```rust
let (i, j) = pos.unwrap();
let val = nested_array[i][j];

assert_eq!(i, 3);
assert_eq!(j, 0);
assert_eq!(val, find);
```

---

If you want to find multiple instances of `20`. Then you simply need to replace [`find_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find_map) with [`filter_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map):

```rust
let positions = nested_array.iter().enumerate().filter_map(|(i, arr)| {
    let j = arr.iter().position(|x| x == &find)?;
    Some((i, j))
});
```

---

If you can have multiple instances of `20` in the same row, then you can do something like this:

```rust
let positions = nested_array
    .iter()
    .enumerate()
    .flat_map(|(i, arr)| {
        let arr = arr.iter().enumerate();
        std::iter::repeat(i).zip(arr)
    })
    .filter_map(|(i, (j, val))| (val == &find).then_some((i, j)));
```

All of this can of course be written in a few variations. So the main take away is [`find_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find_map), [`filter_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map), and [`position()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.position).